# com.liferay.portlet.ResourceResponseImpl cannot be cast to javax.portlet.ActionResponse

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet

I'am using Liferay 6.1.1 and Primefaces 3.5 with Inter Portlet Communication and i have this error. 
This is my code

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
Projects project = (Projects) event.getObject();
QName qName = new QName("http://liferay.com/events", "ipc.projectSelected");
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ActionResponse actionResponse = (ActionResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
Serializable eventPayload = project;
eventPayload = new EventPayloadWrapper(project, true);
actionResponse.setEvent(qName, eventPayload);
}
```

an in My View.xhhtm i have a dataTable :

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{MyBean.onRowSelect}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This question may have been answered in the [Liferay Forums](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/29973568).